# How do I clone an entire repository into a branch other than master?

Tags: git, github, version-control

**Update**

I think my question has a mistake but @SLaks answer helped me realize that.

---

Based on the research I did, there are a lot of solutions to cloning *from* branches other than master.

However, I want to clone the branch master ( of the source repo ), but not *into* the branch master ( of the current repository I am working on). I want to clone the source repo into a branch called 'previously' which will house all work done previously in the previous repo; I want to leave master clean with only files pertinent to the current repo.

**More context**

Whenever I use the clone command and the url of the source repo, I end up filling the master branch of the current repo with the files from the previous repo. Instead, I want the branch previously to be filled with those files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloning does not affect any current repo in any way; it creates a new repo.

You want to fetch the other repo into yours, then make a branch pointing to its HEAD:

```
git fetch <remote URL>
git branch previous FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Makes sense. 1. Fetching did clone the source into 1 branch, i.e. previously. So that part works. (2) However, none of the code has been cloned; I have an empty folder, with the correct name but nothing inside it. (3) What does your second command do?

Comment: Fetching any kind of code into an existing repo won't create any files; it just updates the git internal repo storage.  You want to create that points to a commit of your choice (which is what my second command does).

Comment: @SLaks Your second command does not check out the files into the working directory either. Either replace it with `git checkout -b previous FETCH_HEAD` or follow it up with `git checkout previous`...